# How to get the list of changed files in a git repo (including submodules) with a single command

Tags: git

I want to get the list of changed files in a git repo (including submodules)
and I'm using this command:

```
git diff HEAD  --name-only && git submodule foreach git diff HEAD  --name-only
```

that displays this:

```
Entering 'submodule name'
<path/to/file>
```

I only want to get the file path, what should I do?

Comment: One workaround is to add `| grep -v '^Entering'` to suppress `Entering 'submodule name'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to add `| grep -v '^Entering'` to suppress `Entering 'submodule name'`. And `git submodule` has `--quiet` to do the job:

```
git submodule --quiet foreach git diff HEAD  --name-only
```